# json decode sorting from variables value

Tags: php

> [ {"play":"hdr.1","name":"1","year":"1994","class":"act bio deo"},
>   {"play":"hdr.2","name":"2","year":"1972","class":"deo bio sil"},
>   {"play":"hdr.3","name":"3","year":"1974","class":"sil moc tel"},
>   {"play":"hdr.5","name":"4","year":"1994","class":"rep sim fal"},
>   {"play":"hdr.6","name":"5","year":"1967","class":"viz tel moc"},
>   {"play":"hdr.7","name":"6","year":"2003","class":"fal deo dec"},
>   {"play":"hdr.8","name":"7","year":"1999","class":"tel act bio"},
>   {"play":"hdr.9","name":"8","year":"1993","class":"mio moc viz"},
>   {"play":"hdr.10","name":"9","year":"1957","class":"fal dec mio"} ]

I have this json.json data and i use this php code to make from all links that i use somewhere:

```
<?php
    $fill = file_get_contents("json.json");
    $tstJson = json_decode($fill);
    foreach($tstJson as $val)
        echo "<a class='".$val->class."' href='?".$val->play."' >".$val->name."</a>";
?>
```

But how do i make this to echo only  the classes that contains "act" ?
Like a sorting mode.

Comment: sorting or filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**strpos()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if 'act' is in class before echoing:

```
foreach($tstJson as $val)
    if (strpos($val->class, 'act') !== false) 
        echo "<a class='".$val->class."' href='?".$val->play."' >".$val->name."</a>";
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/9dsFSoX8)

Answer (score 0):

You just need an `if` with a `preg_match`:

```
<?php
    $fill = file_get_contents("json.json");
    $tstJson = json_decode($fill);
    foreach ($tstJson as $val) {
        if (preg_match('/\bact\b/', $val->class)) {
            echo "<a class='".$val->class."' href='?".$val->play."' >".$val->name."</a>";
        }
    }
?>
```

The `\bact\b` checks that the entire word is `act` (so, for example, `fact` won't match).

Output (with line breaks for readability):

```
<a class='act bio deo' href='?hdr.1' >1</a>
<a class='tel act bio' href='?hdr.8' >7</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
     $fill = file_get_contents("json.json");
       $tstJson = json_decode($fill);
       foreach($tstJson as $val)
       { 
         $act_class = explode(" ", $val->class);
         if(in_array("act", $act_class))
           {
            echo "<a class='".$val->class."' href='?".$val->play."' >".$val->name."</a>";
           }
      }
 ?>
```